# Install gems of ruby 1.9 bins without suffix in openSuSE

Tags: ruby, opensuse, rubygems, gem

I got issue on my openSuSE instances. 
By default in openSuSE after installation by gem utility (gem install some_app) you will got something like that:

```
# some_app1.9
# chef-solo1.9
```

etc.

That a bad behaviour especially if you want automate stuff.

Comment: FYI -- the right way to answer your own question is by adding the answer as an answer (so other people can upvote it, and so the question shows as answered), rather than editing the question to include its own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I try to find out how to remove this appendix/suffix and find a solution based on [this article](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/updates/12.2/x86_64/ruby19-devel-extra-1.9.3.p392-3.26.1.x86_64.html):

1. Install ruby19-devel-extra by `zypper install ruby19-devel-extra`
2. Second install gems by adding option "--no-format-executable":

   ```
   gem install chef --no-format-executable
   ```

Comment: If you aren't using `rvm` you are most likely wasting time.